# CSS vertical alignment of inline/inline-block elements

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to get several `inline` and `inline-block` components aligned vertically in a `div`. How come the `span` in this example insists on being pushed down? I've tried both `vertical-align:middle;` and `vertical-align:top;`, but nothing changes.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <a></a><a></a>
  <span>Some text</span>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
a {
    background-color:#FFF;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:solid black 1px;
}

div {
    background:yellow;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
span {
    background:red;
}
```

​
**RESULT:**
[image]

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TFPx8/2/)**

Comment: note that this won't happen if `<a>` elements contain some text inside them [see this link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13548168/2803565)

Answer (score 325, accepted):

`vertical-align` applies to the elements being aligned, not their parent element. To vertically align the div's children, do this instead:

```
div > * {
    vertical-align:middle;  // Align children to middle of line
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/dfmx123/TFPx8/1186/

**NOTE**: `vertical-align` is relative to the current text line, not the full height of the parent `div`. If you wanted the parent `div` to be taller and still have the elements vertically centered, set the `div`'s `line-height` property instead of its `height`. Follow *jsfiddle* link above for an example.

Comment: This stops working if you specify a height for the outer `div`.

Comment: @AbhranilDas `vertical-align` is relative to the current text line, not the parent element. To make this work as you want, set the div's `line-height` instead of its `height`.

Comment: Actually this is a false answer. Go to the fiddle and change the line-height to line-height:40px; then you can see that there is more space above than below, which is exactly my problem! The only true solution I see here is flex-box or maybe absolute position. I was coming here for finding a solution that does not involve any of those two methods I mentioned, but it seems these are the best options. See my answer below.

Answer (score 30):

Give `vertical-align:top;` in `a` & `span`. Like this:

```
a, span{
 vertical-align:top;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/TFPx8/10/

Answer (score 6):

Simply floating both elements left achieves the same result.

```
div {
background:yellow;
vertical-align:middle;
margin:10px;
}

a {
background-color:#FFF;
width:20px;
height:20px;
display:inline-block;
border:solid black 1px;
float:left;
}

span {
background:red;
display:inline-block;
float:left;
}
```

Comment: The problem with floating them to the left is that they will wrap to the next line when the browser gets too small. Sometimes you need items to stay inline even beyond the browser bounds and thus, `inline-block` is the only solution.

Comment: While that wrapping problem can be in an issue, I'd say that this is a really good solution for those cases where wrapping is okay.  It's elegant, speaks to the spirit of the desired effect and doesn't require modifications to the parent.

Answer (score 5):

For fine tuning the position of an `inline-block` item, use top and left:

```
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
```

Thanks [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/tips-aligning-icons-text/#article-header-id-3)!

Comment: [`translate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#translate%28%29) is also possible.

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Comment: Extremely handy. Sometimes this is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

I was not satisfied by the accepted answer. Its not truly centering, which I showcase/proof in my first example, so I played around and the two solutions I found is the classical `top: 50%` plus `translateY(-50%)` with absolute positioning or using flex-box.

###### Sidenotes:

I personally find the workings of the `vertical-align` somehwhat complicated and I'm uncertain if this can be used for truly centered the entire child inline-block like the flex-box can.
Info can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align). But mind these two fact:

> baseline (default)
>
> ```
> Aligns the baseline of the element with the baseline of its parent. The baseline of some replaced elements, like <textarea>, is
> ```
>
> not specified by the HTML specification, meaning that their behavior
> with this keyword may vary between browsers.
>
> middle
>
> ```
> Aligns the middle of the element with the baseline plus half the x-height of the parent.
> ```

As you can see  `vertical-align: middle` involves the x-height and is more text-related an thusly does not "truly" center, the entire element.

#### Example 1:

Maybe you need to zoom in to see the subtle difference, I made some outlines to make it more visibly. Note, that if not set, the default for `vertical-align` is `baseline`

```css
div {
  background: orange;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

div>* {
  line-height: normal;
}

a {
  background-color: #FFF;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  outline: 1px dotted black;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}

.va-m {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

span {
  height: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: 1px dotted black;
  outline-offset: 9px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  Pure text
  <a>Not really centered</a>
  <a class="va-m">Not really centered</a>
  <span>Centered</span>
</div>
```

#### Example 2: Flexbox

([Here is a good guide.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/))

```css
a {
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid black 1px;
}

div {
  height: 40px;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

span {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
  <span>Some text</span>
</div>
```