# White space right before first child within a parent supplied height

Tags: html, css

I just can't realize why first child has white space right after parent's "border". What is my mistake?

```
.content {
    font-size: 22px;
}

.content__row {
    height: 150px;
}

.content__column_half {
    width: 49%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #000000;
    background-color: graytext;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x8ant22n/

Comment: It's unclear what you mean...what border and what whitespace? Do you mean the vertical alignment - https://jsfiddle.net/x8ant22n/

Comment: ...or the space between the inline-block items - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Comment: I meant the vertical aligment

Comment: Then it's just `vertical-align:top` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670469/css-vertical-alignment-of-inline-inline-block-elements

Comment: .auth_button padding-top:5px gives that vertical indent of the first div. remove that. profit.

Comment: wow, but why ".auth_button padding-top:5px" affects on first "content__column_half"? Is it unclear only to me?

Comment: u have 2 blocks with inline-block display side by side without specifing vertical-align. by default it's value is baseline. in this case the text signs in the both divs are on the same horizontal line. the more top padding you give in .auth-button the more two of the lines shift down together on the same line. it's the texts inside that are aligned, not containers

Answer (score 1):

Add this to `.content__column_half`:

```
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 0 .5%;
```

And remove: `display: inline-block`.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x8ant22n/2/

---

Flex Alternative:

Add `display: flex` to `.content__row` and add `flex-grow: 1` to .content__column_half`.

Remove `display: inline-block`

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x8ant22n/3/

Comment: Thanks, but why "display: inline-block" doesn't behave this way?

Comment: It does, `inline-block` is the newer `float` alternative, but I really do not know why you had the empty space on top. But`inline-block` was causing it.

Comment: I have also created a `flex` alternative, answer edited