# Why won't elements stay on the same line?

Tags: html, css, css-position, font-size

I've tried all sorts of displays and positions to get all these elements on the same line, but for some reason, the button "Add" is in a weird position. Also, the center of the slash isn't horizontally aligned with the center of the boxes, it should be a little further up. The main issue is getting all of these elements on the same line, I want to somehow have their centers all be on the same imaginary horizontal line. How do I do that?
Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blueroof/h3ws48fz/7/),

```css
#slash {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #E86B00;
  display: inline-block;
}

textarea {
  border: 3px solid #FF9333;
  resize: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
}

textarea:focus {
  border: 3px solid #E86D00;
  outline: none;
}

button {
  height: 30;
  width: 70;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #FF7800;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #E86D00;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:active {
  background-color: #FF8315;
  border-right: 2px solid #DCDCDC;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #DCDCDC;
  border-top: 2px solid #ADADAD;
  border-left: 2px solid #ADADAD;
}
```

```html
<textarea type="textarea" id="fir" value="" onfocus="this.value=''"></textarea>
<p id="slash"> / </p>
<textarea type="textarea" id="sec" value="" onfocus="this.value=''"></textarea>
<button onclick="TestGrade();">Add</button>
```

Comment: LMGTFY... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670469/css-vertical-alignment-of-inline-inline-block-elements... https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp...

Comment: you can use flex box css. it will help you.

[https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

align-items:'center' this property will help you set all content in vertical middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must align them with `vertical-align`. I have added that to the elements below.

```css
  #slash {
     font-size: 50px;
     color: #E86B00;
     display: inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
  }
  textarea {
     border: 3px solid #FF9333;
     resize: none;
     height:30px;
     width:50px;
vertical-align:middle;
  }
  textarea:focus{
     border: 3px solid #E86D00;
     outline: none;
  }
  button {
    height: 30; width: 70;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #FF7800;
vertical-align:middle;
  }
  button:hover {
    background-color: #E86D00;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  button:active {
    background-color: #FF8315;
    border-right: 2px solid #DCDCDC;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #DCDCDC;
    border-top: 2px solid #ADADAD;
    border-left: 2px solid #ADADAD;
  }
```

```html
<textarea type="textarea" id="fir" value="" onfocus="this.value=''"></textarea>
<p id = "slash"> / </p>
<textarea type="textarea" id="sec" value="" onfocus="this.value=''"></textarea>
<button onclick="TestGrade();" >Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you keep all the element inside one div 
and add these css properties to the div: display:flex, align-items:center